# What am I missing in basic OLS?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, least-squares

I must first admit that I haven't done stats in a loooong time, but I need to do some rudimentary analyses.  My issue is that my findings just don't "look right," so I want to see if anyone can spot any glaring issues in an OLS model.  My concern is that I have extremely low correlations for everything, even things that I think should be highly related, and the majority of my variables are significant in my model.  Any help would be much appreciated.  My DV is continuous (with a max of 1), my IVs are all nominal or ordinal, with the exception of number of arrests.

Right click on the links below and click "view image" to see.

[Valid Correlation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/14h9ebm77f9s9fu/corr.JPG?dl=0)

[Valid Sum](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh736rx9fp4snyf/sum.JPG?dl=0)

[Valid OLS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bx2mse7bgxhhb3t/ols.JPG?dl=0)

[Valid RVFPlot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4id036e9iiugzqs/rvfplot.JPG?dl=0)

[Valid LVR2Plot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1egnf5uvl65nqm1/lvr2plot.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Maybe add the images somewhere that hosts more cleanly?

Comment: I edited your post and fixed the links so they work. Please look at the source so you know how to do it. Or use the link widget (looks like a chain) above the compose window.

Comment: As your question stands now, it is unclear what you are asking. You may have several questions in here that need development on your side. I am pretty sure that your dependent variable requires a transformation, so you can ask "How do I decide if I need a transformation, and how to choose the right one?". If you are concerned with low correlations (I wouldn't be; data are data), you can ask "Do low correlation matter if the final regression is significant?" (and you will probably get a lecture on power analysis in return). And please repost with everything in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check how you are coding race in your model.  It looks like you have five values for race and are treating them as a continious variable.  That probably isn't what you want.
2. You may want to recode gender, fam_support, etc to 0 and 1 (dummy code) to make your coefficients more interpretable.  For that matter, you may want to mean center a number of your variables.
3. It seems likely that num_arr is not normally distributed or you have an outlier (max 62).  You might want to look at that data more carefully.  In a similar vein, plot everything to sanity check your data.  Your leverage plot seems to suggest a number of data points of concern... look at those more carefully and maybe also consider Cooks D or DFFITs.
4. Make sure your data is actually independent.
5. What is the _cons variable, it didn't show up until your regression model results.
6. Your outcomes are restricted in range between 0 and 1, it may make sense to use a link function (even though it probably won't change things all that much).

Comment: It looks like he's using Stata, where `_cons` is the constant that Stata adds by default to regressions.